# Append only selected class from html ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know how can I filter or append only specific class from a html result?

Tried something like this, but did not work

```
 success: function (data) {
                    var $table1= $(data).filter('.toTable1');
                     var $table2= $(data).filter('.toTable2');
                    $('#Table1').append('<tr>' + $table1+ '</tr>');
                    $('#Table2').append('<tr>' + $table2+ '</tr>');
```

data contains this code

```
   @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ManualJournalDetails"))
    {
        <tr class="toTable1" id="@Model.Guid">
            <td>Hello First World</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="toTable2" id="@Model.Guid">
            <td>Hello Second </td>
       </tr>
```

'What i want to do is append the result with a class of `toTable1` to `TABLE1` and `toTable2` to `TABLE2`, how can I possibly do this?

Thanks

Comment: So what is the problem here? What is your HTML?

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want to append row with class toTale1 to the table or to div( i cannot see div in your question anywhere, no html). give proper example and html so that we can clearly get what issue you are facing

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar sorry, already updated the question thanks

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal sorry, already updated the question thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning `tr` and again creating `tr` while appending which is not required. You can use `.find()` to get class row and then append it to respective tables. See below code

```
success: function (data) {
      //create jQuery object to perform find
      var $data = $(data);
      var $table1= $data.find('.toTable1');
      var $table2= $data.find('.toTable2');
      $('#Table1').append($table1);
      $('#Table2').append($table2);
```